# Cant use Windows references

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, reference, .net-4.5

I'm trying to test out this **[Animation Timeline Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.animationtimeline.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)** found here from the **MSDN** site, but having problems getting the proper references loaded. I'm currently targeting **.NET 4.5**. Everything after `System.Windows` is causes an error saying that none of the last 5 exists in `System.Windows`. But when I check the list of references/try to add them in, none of them (other than `System.Windows`) are listed.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Navigation; <--- From here down, none exist
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

Is there a way to get **Visual Studio** to recognize them?

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to them

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi I've tried, but other than System.Windows, the rest doesn't show up in the list to add them.

Comment: Have you tried to browse to the actual dll.  If it's not in the GAC it won't show in the list

Comment: You do realize that you are mixing winforms and Wpf, you will either need to add the PresentationCore and PresentationFramework references to your project or just go down to WPF interoperability in your Toolbox and add an ElementHost to your Form, it will bring along the Wpf references when you add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AnimationTimeline` class is a part of Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF).  I suspect your project was created as a Windows Forms application.  These are very different technologies and normally you don't mix them together, except in special cases.

If you look at the same MSDN page *that you linked us*, you will see that it is written as follows:

> **Assembly**:  PresentationCore (in PresentationCore.dll)

So in order to use that class you must add a reference to PresentationCore.dll.  You also usually want to reference PresentationFramework.dll and WindowsBase.dll at least for the core WPF functionality.

If you simply create a new WPF Application in Visual Studio it should have the appropriate references.